# Can not resolve symbol Fragment XX impl

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I have a fragment under mainActivity, and the mainActivity using data binding wrap fragment:

```
// activity_main.xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</layout>
```

The LoginFragment also use data binding with LoginViewModel:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="loginViewModel"
            type="com.example.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>

    ...
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

But when I compile project, the line `import com.example.dccandroidapp.FragmentLoginBindingImpl;`, it report a error show the binding is false.

Comment: Add your full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled data binding in app/build.gradle? Also, try to clean the project, then rebuild it again - if you haven't done these steps yet.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happen because I haven't use the `supportFragmentManager` to initialize the fragment in activity. Adding this to onCreate in MainActivity.

```
        val currentFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)

        if (currentFragment == null) {
            val fragment = LoginFragment()
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit()
        }
```